# Setting spark storageFraction has no efffect. It doesn't even crash with nonsense value

Tags: caching, memory, configuration, apache-spark, storage

I am trying to change the spark environment variable "spark.memory.storageFraction". I have tried to do this in various ways:

- As a parameter to my spark-submit command
- Saved in a config file that I attached to my spark-submit
- In the scala code via .set("spark.memory.storageFraction","0.1")

When i check the spark application UI under "Spark properties" it clearly shows that the variable is set, but it has no effect on the storage memory when I look at the "Executors"-section of the UI.

Even if I add a nonsense value like such:

.set("spark.memory.storageFraction","Blah blah blah")

The program doesn't seem to be affected at all. In fact, the "blah blah blah"-value is displayed under spark properties.

**I am using spark 1.5**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511451/626431

Answer (score 0):

Try `spark.storage.memoryFraction` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not affect the properies at all, either =/