# Setting "spark.memory.storageFraction" in Spark does not work

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to tune the memory parameter of Spark. 
I tried:

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.memory.storageFraction","0.1") //sparkSession has been created
```

After I submit the job and checked Spark UI. I found "Storage Memory" is still as before. So the above did not work.

What is the correct way to set "spark.memory.storageFraction"?

I am using Spark 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I face same problem , after read some code from spark github I think the "Storage Memory" on spark ui is misleading, it's not indicate the size of storage region，actually it represent the maxMemory:

```
maxMemory =  (executorMemory - reservedMemory[default 384]) * memoryFraction[default 0.6]
```

check these for more detail ↓↓↓

[spark ui executors-page source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/exec/ExecutorsPage.scala#L150-L152)

[getMaxmemory source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/memory/UnifiedMemoryManager.scala#L206-L228)

Comment: Is this fixed now in Spark UI ? What is meaning for storage memory in Executors tab in Spark UI?

Answer (score 2):

As per [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/configuration.html#memory-management) the `spark.memory.storageFraction` option configures just the   *"amount of storage memory **immune to eviction**"*, not the upper limit. In fact all the memory not used for execution can be used for storage and the upper limit of the storage memory, assuming no memory is used for execution, therefore is: `(executor memory - reserved memory) * memoryFraction`).
See also [Memory Management Overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/tuning.html#memory-management-overview).

In the column's tooltip in the UI they correctly state that it displays the *"total available memory for storage..."*.

This means that you won't see the effect of the `spark.memory.storageFraction` in the UI column you are probably looking at.