# Changing "spark.memory.storageFraction" has no effect on 'Storage Memory' column in Executors tab

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to play with the **spark.memory.storageFraction** parameter in order to decrease the amount of memory saved for cache.
However, setting it to 0.1, 0.5 or even 0.9 doesn't show any change in the "Storage" column on the Executors tab:

[image]

Changing the **spark.memory.fraction** parameter is the only way I see a change in this column, but that's not the way to decrease the storage memory.

I'm using spark 1.6.1 and also setting **spark.memory.useLegacyMode** to false.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511451/626431

Answer (score 0):

> I'm (...) setting spark.memory.useLegacyMode to false.

That's your problem. Specifically:

> `spark.memory.useLegacyMode`  `false`
>
> Whether to enable the legacy memory management mode used in Spark 1.5 and before. The legacy mode rigidly partitions the heap space into fixed-size regions, potentially leading to excessive spilling if the application was not tuned. The following deprecated memory fraction configurations are not read unless this is enabled: `spark.shuffle.memoryFraction`
> `spark.storage.memoryFraction`
> `spark.storage.unrollFraction`

In other words, you have to enable legacy mode, to use these properties.

Comment: I looked at this documentation before asking and I don't think you are right, since the deprecated relevant property as they state is 'spark.storage.memoryFraction', but I am using 'spark.memory.storageFraction'.