# Change spark.memory.storageFraction

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, pyspark, bigdata

I'm trying to reduce the value of `spark.memory.storageFraction` in the code like this:

```
sparkSession = (SparkSession
                    .builder
                    .appName(app_name)
                    .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")
                    .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
                    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "512M")
                    .config("spark.memory.storageFraction", 0.1)
                    .config("spark.executor.memory", "3g")
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate())
```

Also I have tried it in the spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.pyspark.python=python3.6 --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1 --driver-memory 2g --num-executors 6 --py-files packages.zip jobs/case1/case1.py
```

When launching the job I can see this configuration in the spark configuration via:

```
spark_logger.info(sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf().getAll())
```

But it doesn't get any effect in the spark web UI.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71511451/626431