# how to decrease storage memory in spark 2.3?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I run a pyspark job to do some transformation and save result into orc files in hdfs, my spark conf are:

```
   --driver-memory 12G --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 32G ${dll_app_spark_options} --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2047 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g --conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.7 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4096 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200
```

my job always fails, because Yarn kill executor for memory (exceeding memory limits)
[image]

storage memory for executors and driver as bellow
[image]

DataFrame to save contain 1 million rows and 400 columns (type of columns array(Float)
I want to decrease storage memory, I tried spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.7 but it gives same results
any idea please ?

Comment: I think using this parameter spark.memory.storageFraction you can tune your storage memory and for Spark UI check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512231/setting-spark-memory-storagefraction-in-spark-does-not-work

Answer (score 2):

To control storage memory you can use following

```
--conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1
```

or

```
--conf spark.memory.fraction=0.1
```

[image]

Please refer - [spark-management-overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview)